# Only set text as link

Tags: html, css, hyperlink

So when ever I wrap a header in an anchor I end up being able to click on the "side" of a link and it'll still work. I *only* want to be able to click the text, not surrounding area. Here's the code

```
<a href="#" id="link"><h1 class="out">Click here ----></h1></a>
```

And a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/8weUA/). Any ideas? I wasn't really sure what to search for.

Comment: Don't forget to escape your `>` with `&gt;`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Put the anchor inside the `h1` if you only want the text clickable, not the entire block.

```
<h1 class="out"><a href="#" id="link">The reset link has already been used</a></h1>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/8weUA/1/

Comment: Any way to do it via CSS? Cause then I'd have to restyle all the text.... I'm pretty sure I've seen it done in CSS.

Comment: @user302975 You can also leave your html as is but wrap that part in a `p` tag.

Comment: @user302975 Yes, but you'd have to change the behavior of the h1 so it doesn't take up the full width of its container (That's the default behavior of a block-level element). Personally, I recommend putting it inside the h1 so it would be a bit more proper, but you could probably do a display: inline-block; on the h1.

Answer (score 0):

This should do it

```
<h1 class="out"><a href="#" id="link">Click here ----></a></h1>
```